# Runtime's exec() method is not redirecting the output

Tags: java, shell, process, runtime.exec

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh somescript.sh &> out.txt");
```

I am running this command using Java.  The script is running but it's not redirecting its stream to the file.  Moreover, the file `out.txt` is not getting created.

This script runs fine if I run it on shell.

Any ideas?

Comment: why is that ampersand(&) ?

Comment: its for redirecting both output stream as well as error stream to the file

Comment: have you searched your system for the file?

Comment: 1) Read the [runtime.exec info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  Implement ***all*** the recommendations in the linked Java World article. 2) Then ignore it refers to `exec` & use a `ProcessBuilder(String[])` constructor. 3) I heard something about pipes not working in a Java process.

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes its not getting created .the command sh somescript.sh is running anyways

Comment: Are you sure it's not being created? Did you check the directory in `System.getProperty("user.dir");` ?

Comment: can you be sure that it is not created? maybe it's just not in the directories where you think it should be.... maybe it's in an other directory

Comment: Pipes (and redirects) wouldn't usually work on UNIX because they are things that the shell does. In this case sh is being executed. The behaviour of `Runtime.exec` is largely undocumented.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to redirect.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "somescript.sh");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("out.txt"));
builder.redirectError(new File("out.txt"));
Process p = builder.start(); // may throw IOException
```

Comment: It works absolutely fine.Thanks ..Are there any references where i can read a bit more about this ,i have to do a lot of things on shell using java.So it will be useful for me

Comment: @user2110167 [API document about ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: One More thing, if i want to add some options into the command like somecommand -o "outputdirectory" -i "inputfilelist" ,how can i add -o and -i options?

Comment: @user2110167 `new ProcessBuilder("somecommand", "-o", "outputdirectory", "-i", "inputfilelist");`

Comment: @johnchen902 I wrote the code as per you have stated .even when we are redirecting both the streams into a file ,there is some output which stays missing .if i run "sh somescript.sh &> out.txt" on shell ,the out.txt file gets each output written by the script,but using process builder and redirecting both the inputs,then it gives output equivalent to writing sh somescript.sh > out.txt .. are we missing anything in the code ..And the script is actually a perl script which calls java functions internally.

Comment: for me can not resolve method redirectOutput and redirectError...:(

Comment: I would think that it wouldn't work to redirect both output streams to the same file in this way.  I would expect two attempts to open the file to occur, and one of them. to fail. 
 Rather, I'd think that you'd specify one and then have a way. of saying to redirect the other one to the one being sent to the file, much like `>blah.out 2>&1`.

Comment: @johnchen902 , the call to redirectError() should have a different filename than the one for redirectOutput(). Could you change the answer to have this line?:

`builder.redirectError(new File("err.txt"));`

Answer (score 7):

When you run a command, there is no shell running and any shell commands or functions are not available.  To use something like `&>` you need a shell.  You have one but you are not passing it to it.  try instead.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "somescript.sh &> out.txt" });
```

Comment: That's not going to compile, is it?

Comment: there is no overloaded exec function which takes such inputs,because its giving compile errors

Comment: @commentators: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "somescript.sh &> out.txt" });`