# Write result from command line in file using Java

Tags: java, file, command-line

I tried to run command line from Java code.

```
public void executeVcluto() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String command = "cmd /c C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\program.exe C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\file.txt 5 >> C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\result.txt";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
    if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Command exit successfully");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Command failed");
    }

}
```

However, the file where output result should be written result.txt is not created. When I execute this command from cmd on windows the file is created and the result is written in it. I get Command exit successfully message. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

output redirection is shell feature, java Process does not understand that.

Some other alternatives are 
1. create a single batch file with above lines and invoke it using ProcessBuilder/Runtime
2.  Use ProcessBuilder and redirect output using output streams.
 Example (it is for shell, will work for batch files too) is here

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new     ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\program.exe", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\file.txt" , "5");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\result.txt"));
builder.redirectError(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\resulterr.txt"));

Process p = builder.start(); // throws IOException
```

(above is tweaked from [Runtime's exec() method is not redirecting the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output))

Answer (score 0):

Try `cmd.exe`, including a path, if necessary.

You're creating an entirely new process, which is different than giving a command to a shell.