# why this is not create a backup file in specified location?

Tags: java, mysql

When this code executes, the file specified in the redirect does not get created. Why not?

```
public class MyDdlSql {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -uroot -psuri biztime >D:data.sql");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using windows. You're using relative path. So you have to look in your current directory (under drive D) or use an absolute path like D:\\data.sql (you have to quote the backslash, or you can use forward slash).

Comment: Also you need to run the program with Administrative permission

Comment: that is also not working...... file not created

Comment: package scheduler;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyDdlSql {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -uroot -psuri biztime >D:\\data22.sql");
   int i=p.waitFor();
   if(i==0){
    System.out.println("success");
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("fail");
   }
  } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
this give the fail and file not created in specified location..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

[Runtime's exec() method is not redirecting the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output)

Redirection is a feature of the shell. So you cannot use it. Instead you should use ProcessBuilder.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("mysqldump", "-uroot", "-psuri", "biztime");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("D:\\data.sql"));
builder.redirectError(new File("error.log"));
Process p = builder.start();
```

Comment: package scheduler;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyDdlSql {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -uroot -psuri biztime >D:\\data22.sql");
   int i=p.waitFor();
   if(i==0){
    System.out.println("success");
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("fail");
   }
  } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
this give the fail and file not created in specified location..........