# Why the following code doesn't work?

Tags: java, linux, command

i'm trying to run shell command in linux via java. most of the commands work, but when i run the following command i get an execption, although it works in the shell:

```
    String command = "cat b.jpg f1.zip > pic2.jpg";

    String s = null;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");

        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

i am getting the error in the console:

cat: >: No such file or directory

cat: pic2.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: I think this might be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the redirection.

> cat: >: No such file or directory

The way to interpret this error message:

- the program `cat` is trying to tell you about a problem
- the problem is that there is no file named `>`

Indeed, `>` is not a file. It's not intended as a file, at all. It's a shell operator to redirect output.

You need to use `ProcessBuilder` to redirect:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cat", "b.jpg", "f1.zip");
builder.redirectOutput(new File("pic2.jpg"));
Process p = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to start a shell (e.g. /bin/bash) which will execute your shell command, replace:

```
String command = "cat b.jpg f1.zip > pic2.jpg";
```

with

```
String command = "bash -c 'cat b.jpg f1.zip > pic2.jpg'";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command it doesn't start a shell like bash unless you do this explicitly.  This means you are running `cat` with four arguments `b.jpg` `f1.zip` `>` `pic2.jpg`  The last two files names don't exist so you get an error.

What you are likely to have intended was the following.

```
String command = "sh -c 'cat b.jpg f1.zip > pic2.jpg'";
```

This will run `sh` which in sees `>` as a special character which redirects the output.