# Modifying other app's database with root in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, root

How can I read and modify the database of an app that I don't own with root.

I tried copying the file to my app's location like this:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /data/user/0/com.maxmpz.audioplayer/databases/folders.db > /data/user/0/com.example.me.myapp/folders.db");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**and:**

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su cp /data/user/0/com.maxmpz.audioplayer/databases/folders.db /data/user/0/com.example.me.myapp/folders.db");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

***But nothing happens (the exception isn't raised).***

Comment: I think you stick to use `cp`... That's a useless use of cat (UUoC), but if there's no exception, what's the problem?

Comment: The file doesn't appear in the directory, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try manually running in the terminal?

Comment: I got: `Unknown id: cp`

Comment: That's because `cp` is not a User account you can `su` to... Did you forget `-c`? You'll be also need to quote the whole command. The `cat` option probably doesn't work because output redirecting doesn't work in Runtime.exec, if I  recall

Comment: If you want to try the cat option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output

Comment: Quateing the command did it, thank you.

Comment: But it still doesn't work from code: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"cp /data/user/0/com.maxmpz.audioplayer/databases/folders.db /data/user/0/com.example.me.firstapp/paDB.db\"");`

Comment: What if you wrote a shell script, placed it on the file system, then `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /path/to/script.sh")`?

Comment: Seems like it won't be easily distributable that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147390/discussion-between-vasil-kalchev-and-cricket-007).