# tshark to txt ">" output command working in terminal but not in java?

Tags: java, tshark

I am trying to output captured packet information to a .txt file. Running the below code in a terminal works (removing the " of course). However java doesn't seem to like ">". I get the following error message;
tshark: A default capture filter was specified both with "-f" and with additional command-line arguments.

`Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"tshark","-f","tcp src port 80","-i","en0","-l",">","raw.txt"});`

However if i use "-w" instead of ">" it outputs the binary data just fine.

Comment: The shell normally handles `>` rather than the application itself.

Comment: Good point. I think the answer to this question should help then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238714/runtimes-exec-method-is-not-redirecting-the-output

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the capture filter, e.g.

`Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"tshark","-f","\"tcp src port 80\"","-i","en0","-l",">","raw.txt"});`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, still getting the same error.