# Printing logcat to a file with filters? Using grep?

Tags: java, android, logging, grep, logcat

I am very easily printing my logcat to file by doing this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "logcat -f test.txt");
```

But I would like to filter the content based on matching words, I thought about using `grep` and the operator `>`to print to file but that didn't work. No file is being created.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d | grep -n \"System.out\" > test.txt");
```

Comment: Does `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "logcat -d | grep -n \"System\\.out\" > test.txt" });` work?

Comment: Nope, it does not.

Comment: Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238948/3832970), using `ProcessBuilder` (like `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "logcat -d | grep -n \"System\\.out\""); builder.redirectOutput(new File("test.txt")); Process p = builder.start();`). Also, maybe try with `bash` rather than `sh`.

Comment: It creates the file but it's empty.

Comment: Did you try to also set `builder.redirectError(new File("test.txt"));`?

Comment: I get 'sh: logcat -d: No such file or directory'